# Connection being reset by client

Tags: python, sockets, networking

So I am trying to have my computer to communicate with a device and I am getting an error of the Ethernet connection reset. The output from the server side looks like this

`Calling accept on socket
   Accepted connection socket csock:10
   Received Ethernet connection from ip: 186.142.1.23
   Warning - the connection socket was reset by the client
   Error -Ethernet connection reset`

The warning line was repeated 11 times. The client output does not output anything. Here is my client code. Sorry I will not be able to provide the server code.

```
import os
import socket

s=socket.socket()
hostname= "186.142.1.23"
port = 49153
s.connect((hostname,port))
s.close()
```

The code seems to be too simple for something to go wrong. So I am not sure if it is some syntax error or something else. The server might be using PyQt4, if that matters at all. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Connection reset by peer" means that you tried to send data when the receiver had already closed the connection (and isn't expecting more data to arrive).

It looks like your server sends some data when you connect to it. Your client should read what it sends before closing the socket.

Answer (score 0):

The client immediately closes the connection whithout waiting or trying to read anything. So when the server tries to write something into the socket, it fails because the client has already closed it.

You should implement a minimal logic in the client (at least sleep some time and then read) to do your tests.